# Retrieve JSON object till level 1

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm reading data from database and converting it to a JSON object which have multiple collections and multiple levels but I only want to retrieve json till level 1 and no related collections or data. I've used following line of code in C# for that purpose

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings() { MaxDepth = 1, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

Above line is returning following

```
{
  "abc": [
    {
      "Id": "TEST-06",
      "No": 1,
      "Code": " ",
      "Description": ".....",
      "Percentage": null,
      "Details": []
    }
  ],
  "xyz": {
    "Id": "TEST-06",
    "No.": 1,
    "Date": "2018/07/06",
    "Enable": 0,
    "Reason": "....."
  }
}
```

I only want the object "abc" but it's also returning xyz.
I searched everywhere and they say use max depth property to serialize json object to specific depth. Can anyone please help with that?

Comment: "abc" and "xyz" are in the same depth in your example.

Comment: @AthulRaj Ohhh I suppose then I was searching wrong the whole time :(
    Is there a way I can get only "abc"?

Comment: You can create a anonymous object with only the field "abc", like `new { abc = obj.abc }`

Comment: @AthulRaj If I have JSON like this

{
  "Id": "TEST-06",
  "No": 1,
  "Code": " ",
  "Description": ".....",
  "Percentage": null,
  "Details": [],
  "xyz": [ {
      "Id": "TEST-06",
      "No.": 1,
      "Date": "2018/07/06",
      "Enable": 0,
      "Reason": "....."
    }
  ]
}
and I want all data except “xyz”. What I can do in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get only "abc" object simply by using JObject property:

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(YourJSonString);
var abcObject = jObject.First;
```

**Update for Without "abc" Object**

Create a class with any name for the JSon main object.

```
public class AnyClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long No { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public object Percentage { get; set; }
    public List<object> Details { get; set; }
    public List<object> xyz { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize your JSon string with this class type:

```
var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnyClass>(jsonString);
```

Now in `deserializeObject`, you would have all properties and xyz object.

Comment: If I have JSON like this

{
  "Id": "TEST-06",
  "No": 1,
  "Code": " ",
  "Description": ".....",
  "Percentage": null,
  "Details": [],
  "xyz": [ {
      "Id": "TEST-06",
      "No.": 1,
      "Date": "2018/07/06",
      "Enable": 0,
      "Reason": "....."
    }
  ]
}
and I want all data except “xyz”. What I can do in that case?

Comment: Then you can do it with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` using typed object. Check my answer, I am going to update it.

Comment: @MaryumSiddique Kindly mark the answer as accepted and up-vote, whether its fully or partial helpful for you. Its encouragement for us.

Comment: My pleasure @MaryumSiddique. Do upvote as well. Its oxygen for contributors.